# 2-way data binding between partials in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Looking to solve what seems to be a fairly straightforward problem, but not sure how to proceed.

I've written a simple one-page angular app and recently started switching it over to `ui.router` (of the awesome angular-ui variety). For the requirements of the app, it allows me to do far more than the regular `ngRoute` module does (especially with nested views).

After transitioning it over, I've found that I'm having trouble getting data to bind between partials. I have a main view with several sub-views that would need to be able to do live data binding between them. This wasn't a problem before, since each of the components existed in one view (I split them up into sub-views/partials and included them with ui-router).

So, here's what I have set up right now:

main view in `index.html` with `ui-view` used to include several partials.

```
main view
   -form partial
   -preview pane partial
   -review partial
   -submission partial
```

I've only created one controller to handle this section of the app; the partials seem to work with the data passed by the controller, but not with data binding between each other.

What I need to do is achieve live data binding between an input in the form partial and the preview partial; what's the best way to go about this? A service, directive?

Thanks everyone!

ps: if you're not familiar with `UI Router`, you can explain in terms of regular `ngRoute` and I can figure it out

**edit:** Here's how my states are being set up:

(main area where partials are included, enclosed by an ng-app directive)

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="contstrain_y_scroll">
        <section>
     <div ui-view="form"></div>
     <div ui-view="tribute"></div>
     <div ui-view="submit"></div>
     <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>                   

    </section>
</div>
```

(in app.js)

```
        $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            views: {
                'sidebar': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.sidebar.html',

                },
                'form': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.form.html',

                },
                'tribute': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.tribute.html',
                },
                'submit': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/submit.html',
                }
            }
        })
```

My controller seems to be working for each partial, but I want to evaluate an expression in one partial (sidebar) based on in input in another (form). Hope this makes my problem a bit clearer; really appreciate the help!

Comment: Normally, for data sharing between different controllers you would use a service. I see no reason why it should be different here.

Comment: True, but this isn't between controllers. I have an ng-model in one partial and an expression in another that I need to communicate with each other. Would a service work for that, too?

Comment: Can you provide the code on how your `states` are being set up? And maybe the snippets of HTML where `partial` interactions occur? I'm still not quite sure why there will be any problem if all partials share the same controller.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll update the question

Comment: Updated; hopefully that makes what I'm trying to get after a bit clearer. Still a bit new to angular and haven't run into this use-case before, so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you have a `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` declaration on your `div`.

By default, when you're using `ui-router`, the controller you specified in your state definition will be applied automatically to the whole page. By declaring it again in HTML, you're basically declaring it twice.

From my understanding, redundant declaration in HTML will very likely create an extra `$scope` in your DOM. And it can make things behave weirdly. Try removing that and see if it helps.

Comment: I removed the controller declaration from the state config area and it's working now; a few other expressions aren't binding but I will check those to be sure they're not erroring for another reason. Thanks!

Comment: Follow up question about Angular in general: are controllers needed for 2-way binding between partials? Don't remember seeing anything about that in the docs but maybe I missed it.

Comment: @markimus All variables you use in HTML need to be stored somewhere. And that somewhere happens to be a `$scope` bound to a controller. If variables are stored in the same controller/$scope, then you can control those variables in one place. So for your problem, it isn't even about two way binding, but rather it's more about scoping issue.

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks! `$scope` seems to be one of the trickier things to really understand well in angular